# Can check ng-form in Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend, angularjs-ng-form

It is the first line

```
<div class="modal-body row" role="form" ng-form id="MarketItemForm" name="MarketItemForm">
```

and if I write

```
console.log($scope.MarketItemForm)
```

I have undefined

I don't where is error, can you help me?

Comment: Well seems like you also lack basic HTML knowledge. A name attribute is not allowed on a `div` element.

Comment: if i use form name in html like ng-show="MarketItemForm.$valid", it's working

Comment: Ok, might be that the directive can compensate for this, but your error is quite clear though. Scope is not injected as a dependency so MarketItemForm is never added to your scope.

Comment: i use routes) thanks,  i've solved this problem))